# Merging columns during SemanticImport

Tags: import

If one is trying to use SemanticImport to import geo data, how does one merge two separate columns (Lat and Lon) into one column that GeoCoordinates needs?

Comment: If my answer was helpful please consider upvoting it also. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your semantically imported `dataset` have columns for `"Latitude"` and `"Longitude"` with such names and now you replace them with a combined column for Mathematica's representation of geocoordinates as a `GeoPosition` by:

```
dataset=SemanticImport[...]

dataset=Query[All,<|
    KeyDrop[#,{"Latitude","Longitude"}],
    "GeoCoordinate"->GeoPosition[{#Latitude,#Longitude}]
|>&]@dataset
```